# How to find where a method is used in Java project

Tags: java, eclipse, methods, find

I am working on learning a project which was already created by someone else. It was not followed a proper coding method (no comments and so on). Im finding it difficult to find where a method is used. I tried "find" but as it searches only a particular class im unable to get the answer. Im working in eclipse. So can anyone please help me out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can select method that you want to find and use "Ctrl +H" and references search.
[image]

I hope this can help you.

Answer (score 2):

Right click on the method in the editor, and from the pop-up menu select

- **References** > **Project**, or
- **References** > **Workspace**,

depending on whether you want to search only in the current project, or in the entire workspace.

For the *find references in workspace* option, the default keyboard shortcut is:  <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>

After invoking the command, the **Search** window will display an overview of all locations where the method is used.

Comment: actually both the answers work. So im confused which one to accept. Its unfair to select one and leave the other. So i thought of leaving both alone. Hope this is fair

Comment: I would encourage you to accept one. Not only because it will give you a little bit of reputation points, but also because the question can then be used to flag other questions as duplicates. So, I guess it's up to you to figure out which answer you found the most useful. I personally don't mind if you give the accept vote to the other poster.